# What is a good adjective that describes the quality of "having a growth mindset"?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, expressions, synonyms

I'm struggling to find a single word that conveys what is shared in the following statements

- Have a growth mindset
- Be a lifelong learner
- Be a student of the game

Is there a good single adjective that can communicate these in the sample sentence:

**Be *adjective*.**

(the most obvious is "Be growth minded." but that sounds odd to me and I'm hoping for a single word)

Comment: Uh, "hungry"???

Comment: @HotLicks I think that is a great word, but far too ambiguous when standing alone. I'm hoping for the same level of clarity as "be growth minded" brings even with zero context.